# How to add license functionality in my VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am using VB.NET for coding and SQL Server 2005 for database.

My application is ready for release. Just on thing missing before I can go live.

I want to **implement license concept in my application**.

My **license** file can be **text or xml file**. In which there should be some **encrypted** matter which will be used for validate the application.

Please suggest how I can implement this functionality in my application

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Solution

Comment: Related question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525378/how-can-i-make-my-product-as-a-trial-version-for-30-days>

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889902/what-off-the-shelf-licensing-system-will-meet-my-needs, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275196/most-secure-way-to-license-software, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517628/how-to-license-my-net-application-remotely-but-occasionally-connected

Comment: Do you have any web services in your application?

Comment: No I don't have any web service in my application